# QtPlugin Cannot Load Library

Tags: c++, qt, plugins

I am using Qt 4.8.3 on Linux with GCC. I am trying to create a modular application with QtPlugin. The application describes some base functionality and then a host of plugins will provide all of the unique functionality. Each plugin uses a factory to provide multiple instances of a class and consists of the factory class and the class to be provided.

At the moment, the application is compiling, but is not executing and I am getting errors such as `Cannot load library ~: (~: undefined symbol: _ZTI8Base16staticMetaObjectE)`. I am not sure how to fix this error. Removing all mention of Base fixes the problem, but the instances need to be derived from that class, so I don't think that will work.

I've included the structure of the project below with the executable and a single plugin (they are all currently identical and having the same problem).

Thank you very much for your assistance.

#### directory structure

```
main_project
+- main_project.pro
+- app/
| +- app.pro
| +- main.cpp
| +- factoryinterface.h
| +- base.h
| +- base.cpp
|
+- counter/
  +- counter.pro
  +- counter.h
  +- counterfactory.cpp
  +- counterfactory.h
  +- counter.cpp
```

#### main_project.pro

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    app \
    counter
```

#### app.pro

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

DESTDIR = ../
TARGET = app_exec
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    base.cpp

HEADERS += \
    base.h \
    factoryinterface.h
```

#### factoryinterface.h

```
#ifndef FACTORYINTERFACE_H
#define FACTORYINTERFACE_H

#include <QtPlugin>
#include "base.h"

class FactoryInterface {
public:
    virtual ~FactoryInterface() {}
    virtual Base *get() = 0;
    virtual QString name() = 0;
};

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(FactoryInterface,
                    "com.example.FactoryInterface/1.0")

#endif // FACTORYINTERFACE_H
```

#### base.h

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

#include <QObject>

#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QHash>

class Base : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Base(QObject *parent = 0);
    virtual ~Base();

    virtual QString name();

signals:

public slots:

protected:
    QString name_;
};

#endif // BASE_H
```

#### base.cpp

```
#include "base.h"

Base::Base(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

Base::~Base()
{
}

QString Base::name()
{
    return name_;
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

#include <QDir>
#include <QPluginLoader>
#include <QDebug>
#include "factoryinterface.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QDir pluginDir(a.applicationDirPath());
    pluginDir.cd("plugins");
    foreach(QString filename, pluginDir.entryList(QDir::Files))
    {
        QPluginLoader loader(pluginDir.absoluteFilePath(filename));
        QObject *plugin = loader.instance();

        if (plugin)
        {
            FactoryInterface *i = qobject_cast<FactoryInterface*>(plugin);

            if (i)
            {
                qDebug() << " :" << i->name();
            }
        } else {
            qDebug() << loader.errorString();
        }
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

#### counter.pro

```
QT       -= gui
CONFIG   += plugin

TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget(counter)
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += COUNTER_LIBRARY

SOURCES += counter.cpp \
    counterfactory.cpp

HEADERS += counter.h \
    counterfactory.h

INCLUDEPATH += ../app

DESTDIR = ../plugins

symbian {
    MMP_RULES += EXPORTUNFROZEN
    TARGET.UID3 = 0xE5B38B75
    TARGET.CAPABILITY = 
    TARGET.EPOCALLOWDLLDATA = 1
    addFiles.sources = counter.dll
    addFiles.path = !:/sys/bin
    DEPLOYMENT += addFiles
}

unix:!symbian {
    maemo5 {
        target.path = /opt/usr/lib
    } else {
        target.path = /usr/lib
    }
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

#### counter.h

```
#ifndef COUNTER_H
#define COUNTER_H

#include <QObject>
#include "base.h"

class Counter : public Base {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Counter();
};

#endif // COUNTER_H
```

#### counter.cpp

```
#include "counter.h"


Counter::Counter()
{
    name_ = "Counter";
}
```

#### counterfactory.h

```
#ifndef COUNTER_H
#define COUNTER_H

#include <QObject>
#include "factoryinterface.h"
#include "base.h"
#include "counter.h"

class CounterFactory : public QObject, public FactoryInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(FactoryInterface)
public:
    explicit CounterFactory(QObject *parent = 0);
    Base *get();
    QString name();

signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // COUNTER_H
```

#### counterfactory.cpp

```
#include "counterfactory.h"


CounterFactory::CounterFactory(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

Base *CounterFactory::get()
{
    return new Counter;
}

QString CounterFactory::name()
{
    return "Counter";
}

Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(counter, CounterFactory)
```

**Edit:** Updated error message after compiling in Debug mode.

**Edit:** I tried exporting/importing the BaseNode class, but this did not work either. I'm not sure if it is entirely incorrect or if I am doing it incorrectly. The following change was made to the Base class (BASE_LIBRARY was added to DEFINES in the app.pro file):

```
#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(BASE_LIBRARY)
#  define BASESHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define BASESHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

class BASESHARED_EXPORT Base : public QObject {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be adding the Base class to the counter.pro file. I've listed the full updated counter.pro file below, but the only change was the addition to HEADERS and SOURCES.

#### counter.pro

```
QT       -= gui
CONFIG   += plugin

TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget(counter)
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += COUNTER_LIBRARY

SOURCES += counter.cpp \
    counterfactory.cpp \
    ../app/base.cpp

HEADERS += counter.h \
    counterfactory.h \
    ../app/base.h

INCLUDEPATH += ../app

DESTDIR = ../plugins

symbian {
    MMP_RULES += EXPORTUNFROZEN
    TARGET.UID3 = 0xE5B38B75
    TARGET.CAPABILITY = 
    TARGET.EPOCALLOWDLLDATA = 1
    addFiles.sources = counter.dll
    addFiles.path = !:/sys/bin
    DEPLOYMENT += addFiles
}

unix:!symbian {
    maemo5 {
        target.path = /opt/usr/lib
    } else {
        target.path = /usr/lib
    }
    INSTALLS += target
}
```